# Symfony php error message createQueryBuilder adds a WHERE

Tags: php, symfony

I have moved an app from a PHP5 to a PHP7 server. It runs almost smoothly except with a bug in a query builer creation. I have a form in which I take elements from an entity user and wnated to order them. As you can see I do not have a WHERE in my query:

```
->add('user', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MyappAppliBundle:User',
                'property' => 'name',
                'required' => false,
                'empty_value' => '',
                'empty_data' => null,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $br) {
                    return $br->createQueryBuilder('qb')
                        ->orderBy('qb.name', 'ASC');
                }
```

However, when I try to open my form, I have the following error message:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 55: Error: Expected Literal, got 'ORDER'

SELECT qb FROM Myapp\AppliBundle\Entity\User qb WHERE ORDER BY qb.name AS
```

I do not understand why there is a WHERE added here!

If I remove the createQueryBuilder, the form appears perfectly (except the users are not sorted), otherwise I have the error message.

If someone would have an idea, that would be great!

Thanks a lot

EDIT: I am using symfony2 (version 2.3.9 to be precise!)

EDIT 2: I have moved to symfony2.7 now and have changed a little bit the add:

```
->add('user', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MyappAppliBundle:User',
                'choice_translation_domain' => true,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'required' => false,
                'placeholder' => '',
                'empty_data' => null,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $br) {
                    return $br->createQueryBuilder('qb')
                        ->orderBy('qb.name', 'ASC');
                }
            ))
```

However I still have the same issue with this WHERE thats seems coming out of nowhere.

Comment: You should provide more information like which symfony version you use

Comment: Hi, I do not know if you saw my edit but I am using symfony 2.3.9.

Comment: For info, I migrated to 2.7 and I still get the same error message. I do not understand where the WHERE comes from...!

Comment: You should try debug it. dump($br->createQueryBuilder('qb')->getDQL()); and dump($br->createQueryBuilder('qb')->orderBy('qb.name', 'ASC')->getDQL());

Comment: wow that is strange. It give the correct query  SELECT qb FROM Myapp\AppliBundle\Entity\User qb ORDER BY qb.name ASC. However the error message is still there. I really do not understand what happens here.

Comment: Are you sure you have cleared your cache properly?

Comment: I have used rm -rf app/cache/* and rm -rf app/logs/cache, I have also tried sudo php app/console cache:clear but still the same issue

Comment: Maybe update your vendors with composer?

Comment: which vendor then? The process I followed for my project was: I had a project on a ubuntu14 php5 symfony 2.3, my it provider created a new machine ubuntu18 php7 and imported the project as is. I began to have the problems. So I tried updating symfony to 2.7 but still have the problem. Maybe there has been an issue during the reinstallation of the process?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179568/discussion-between-iiirxs-and-stap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had

```
"doctrine/orm": "2.2.*"
```

in my composer.json... I modified it to

```
"doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.*"
```

I ran composer update and it updated doctrine/orm to 2.5.14.
The problem is now solved!

Thanks for the help!